# How to avoid timestamp in InfluxDB query?

Tags: influxdb

I want to make a query to an InfluxDB database, but I don't want to get the timestamp. Lets say I have a query like this:

```
SELECT value FROM measurement;
```

But as result I have two columns; timestamp and value.
How can I avoid timestamp and just query specified columns?

Comment: Don't know if that's possible. You usually want the timestamp with timeseries data. It's not really timeseries data without a timestamp.
Can't you just ignore the time column if you don't need it ? What's the usecase?

Comment: Just want data for machine learning techniques. It's not possible to avoid I'll just ignore it. Thankyou for the response!